# Apply rules to messages in mailbox

Tags: mail.app

I created some rules in `Mail 6.6` application.

Now, I want to apply these rules on my existing mails in mailbox, not just to the inbox, that is going to my mailbox after creation of the rules.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I just got blasted with thousands of e-mails from our error system, and for some reason rules wasn't able to handle all of those mails at once. Manually using Apply Rules puts them in their appropriate folder, but I had to smash Apply Rules like 5 times to get it to work for all of my Cmd+A selected messages, or maybe it was just super laggy. The question is, why didn't the rules apply?

Comment: Yes I too get a storm of emails I don't want clogging my inbox and want to delete later but only after they've been in another mailbox for a day. It seems like there's no solution for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To apply the rules to existing messages, just select the mailbox and use "Apply Rules" from the "Message" menu. Or use the shortcut <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

[image: Screenshot: Apply Rules]

Comment: This does not work in Mail.app 11.2.  The `Apply Rules` item on the `Message` menu only applies to selected messages.

Comment: @SamAxe just plug in the power adapter to your MacBook

Answer (score 8):

Best and easiest solution - Select all emails from that folder you want to apply rules, (probably a cmd + A) and Select 'Apply Rules' on right click menu.